# HTML 5 Canvas - Dynamically include multiple images in canvas

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas

I need to include multiple images in a `canvas`. I want to load them dynamically via a `for-loop`.

I tried a lot but in the best case only the last image is displayed. I check this [tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663759/is-it-possible-to-use-multiple-images-in-an-html5-canvas) but I still get only the last image.

For explanation, here's my latest code(basically the one from the other post):

```
 for (var i = 0; i <= max; i++)
{
    thisWidth = 250;
    thisHeight = 0;
    imgSrc = "photo_"+i+".jpg";
    letterImg = new Image();
    letterImg.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(letterImg,thisWidth*i,thisHeight);
    }
    letterImg.src = imgSrc;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ummm, can letterImg onload() hold more than one function pointer?

Comment: dunno... how can i avoid this?

Comment: @thatidiotguy you can only have one `.onload`, but in this case it's being put on a different element each time so it doesn't matter.  If you want more than one on an element I think you can use `addEventListener('load', ...)`.

Comment: That's not the problem, @thatidiotguy and Alnitak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `onload` event happens asynchronously and by then the loop variable is already at last value.
You can use closures to fix it:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= max; i++)
{
   thisWidth = 250;
   thisHeight = 0;


   (function(j){
      var imgSrc = "photo_"+j+".jpg";
      var letterImg = new Image();
      letterImg.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(letterImg,thisWidth*j,thisHeight);
      }
      letterImg.src = imgSrc;
   })(i);

}
```

Comment: Damn I was just about to answer it. :(

Comment: i get a syntax error about the `(i)`. sorry, never seen this kind of function before: `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`

Comment: syntax correct now. i also get all images but its always the last one... any idea why?

Comment: Try now, i included image creation in closure.

Comment: I don't think that this is his actual problem. But rather, the definition of `letterImg` is changing. Check out my answer and confirm if so, please...

Comment: `letterImg` was changing because it didn't have `var` before definition and was being created in global scope.

Comment: OK, that's true, I didn't notice that you put it there. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative way of solving your problem...

`letterImg` is just a reference to an image. So, the for loop gets executed n times, and each time, `letterImg` is changed into a new image. Therefor, you only get the latest image drawn.

Here's the code (of course, change the `maxImg` number to a correct value.):

```
images = []; //An array where images are stored.
thisWidth = 250; //This doesn't need to be inside the for-loop.
thisHeight = 0;
maxImg = 342;

//Attach an onload event to an image, that will draw it at (x, y) coordinates.
attach = function(img, x, y)
{
    img.onload = function()
    {
        context.drawImage(img, x, y);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= maxImg; i++)
{
    imgSrc = "photo_" + i + ".jpg";

    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].src = imgSrc;

    attach(images[i], thisWidth*i, thisHeight);
}
```