# HTML5 multiple images in loop

Tags: javascript, html

i have an html5 page which loads an single image. but my requirement is to show multiple images one after other in loop. Please provide your suggestions..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use multiple images in an HTML5 canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663759/is-it-possible-to-use-multiple-images-in-an-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<div id="slider"></div>

<style>
    #slider {
        width: 600px;
        height: 300px;
        background-image: url("img/slide0.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>

<script>
    window.onload = function start() {
        slide();
    }

    function slide() {
        var num = 0, style = document.getElementById('slider').style;
        window.setInterval(function () {
            // increase by num 1, reset to 0
            num = (num + 1) % 9;
            console.log(num);
            style.backgroundImage = "url('img/slide" + num + ".jpg')";
        }, 2000); // repeat forever, polling every x milliseconds
    }

</script>
```

Store the images in the appropriate folder and adjust the count of the image where num is calculated. Currently it is set up for 9 images.

Adjust the time at the end of the setInterval function. Currently the images change every 2000 milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you so much!! i will try and let you know if i face any problem. can we achieve using canvas?

Comment: I assume. Check the comment on your questions - it links to another question / solution using canvas